# Método onResponse no se ejecuta al intentar obtener JSON data de una API

Tags: java, android, json, api, retrofit

**Problema:**

Estoy intentando obtener datos de paises de una API de covid19 para después poder manipularlos. El problema es que a la hora de ejecutar el **onResponse()** este mismo no se estaría ejecutando. Realmente no se que puede ser lo que este fallando,revise mil veces si parsee bien . Les dejo el link de la API para el que quiera consultarlo.

**Link:**
https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/10808728/SzS8rjbc#27454960-ea1c-4b91-a0b6-0468bb4e6712

**MainActivity:**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getCountries();
    }

    
    private void getCountries(){

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.covid19api.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        CovidApi covidApi= retrofit.create(CovidApi.class);

        Call <List<Countries>> call = covidApi.getCountries();



        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Countries>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Countries>> call, Response<List<Countries>> response) {
                System.out.println("Im in"); //This is never executed

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Countries>> call, Throwable t) {


            }
        });

    }
}
```

**Countries class:**

```
public class Countries {
        @SerializedName("Country")
        public String country;
        @SerializedName("Slug")
        public String slug;
        @SerializedName("ISO2")
        public String iSO2;


        public String getCountry() {
            return country;
        }

        public String getSlug() {
            return slug;
        }

        public String getiSO2() {
            return iSO2;
        }
}
```

**API interface:**

```
  public interface CovidApi {

    @GET("countries")
    Call <List<Countries>> getCountries();


}
```

Esto es lo que estoy tratando de obtener en formato JSON, una lista de todos los paises:

https://api.covid19api.com/countries

Answer (score 0):

Para comprobar cual es el problema, añade unos logs dentro de los métodos `onResponse()` y `onFailure`.

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Countries>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Countries>> call, Response<List<Countries>> response) {
                
                 if(!response.isSuccessful()) {
                     Log.d("call", response.code + "")
                     return
                 }

                 Log.d("call", response.body + "") // Si tiene exito

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Countries>> call, Throwable t) {
                 
                 Log.d("call", t.getMessage())
 
            }
        });
```